# VS2013 - decltype of class method does not work as default template parameter does not work

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, decltype

I have a following piece of code:

```
template<typename T1,
         typename T2 = decltype(&T1::method)>
struct Foo {};

struct Bar
{
  void method() { }
};

template<class T> Foo<T> foo(T&)
{
  return Foo<T>();
}

int main()
{           
  Bar t;
  foo(t);
}
```

In short, I want to use decltype of a method as a default template parameter, and VS isn't happy about it:

```
source.cpp(18): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'Foo<T,T::method> foo(T &)'
      With the following template arguments:
      'T=Bar'
```

On the other hand gcc and clang are fine with this (http://ideone.com/VuMZaO). Also, moving decltype to `foo` definition resolves this error.

So - is it a bug in MSVC?

Comment: looks like. report it on microsoft connect. unless i've already reported it (i seem to recall reporting a bug like that).